# "400 Bad Request' error when running Python code with Azure Functions

Tags: python, azure

I am trying to run a Python code with Azure Functions using Visual Studio Code. The code runs well in Spyder but when I copy that to Azure Functions I get a "`400 Bad Request`" error which seems to be a syntax error. Basically I am trying to read a timeseries data from a JSON file, process the data (using pandas module) and then apply some mathematical operations. But it seems that the code which is running well in Spyder or other IDEs, cannot run properly with Azure Functions.
Here is a part of the code:

```
import logging
import pandas as pd
import json

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
    
       data = req.get_json ()
       data_datetime = pd.to_datetime(data['Timestamp'])
       df=data.set_index(data_datetime)
       df.drop('Timestamp',axis=1,inplace=True)
    
       return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(df), mimetype="application/json",)
    except ValueError:
       return func.HttpResponse(
        "Could not parse request body.",
        status_code=400
    )
```

And my JSON file looks like:

```
{ "Timestamp":{"0": "1500069600000","1": "1500073200000"}, "Data":{"0":3,"1":4}}
```

It should be mentioned that Azure Functions work well up to line 11 (i.e., datadata = req.get_json ()), but after that when I have used pandas to convert data to pandas Data Frame, it appears that somehow the following lines are not being executed.

Is there a way to adjust Python code syntax to Azure Functions?

Comment: data = req.get_json() will give you a dictionary. So you need to create the dataframe from the dictionary, perform the necessary column actions, then export out back into a dictionary. Only then can you json.dumps back out.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
try:

   data = req.get_json ()
   data_datetime = pd.to_datetime(data['Timestamp'])
   df=data.set_index(data_datetime)
   df.drop('Timestamp',axis=1,inplace=True)

   return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(df), mimetype="application/json",)
except ValueError:
   return func.HttpResponse(
    "Could not parse request body.",
    status_code=400
)
```

First, change `data = req.get_json ()` to `data = json.loads(req.get_body().decode(encoding='UTF-8'))`

Second, although I dont know why, but `data['Timestamp']` is not allowed.

You should put the Timestamp part directly, and it need two or more:

```
{
    "0": {
      "test1":1500069600000,
      "test2":1500069600000
    },
    "1": {
      "test1":1500073200000,
      "test2":1500069600000
    }
}
```

Third, It seems on your side `df` is json, so when you return it, the return part should be like this:

```
return func.HttpResponse(body=json.dumps(data),status_code=200)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but the issue is that the input JSON file cannot be changed, it is going to be loaded from an HTTP so it might not be possible to change it. Furthermore, the structure should not have "test1" , "test2"

Comment: I'm unable to extract the JSON from get_body(). What is the get_json() function for then? Documentation does not elaborate on usage.

Comment: @Max I also dont find the code of get_json(). get_json() doesn't work on my side, that is why I convert data from request body to json manully.

Comment: ok sorry for hijacking this post. sidetrack a bit - if you specify in the requests a json field with the json payload, you can use the get_json() method.
eg:
response = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', json={'id': 1, 'name': 'Jessa'})

Comment: @NJE Seems your code also have problem when run on a simple python script. pd.to_datetime() dont allow data['Timestamp'].

Comment: But on my side this seems to be working, I mean the pd.to_datetime() works in Spyder.